# how to make a rule in firestore, which can let do all operation to the admin user which is a role field in profiles collection

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am new to Firestore database and making ticket booking system app using react and firbase. For authentication I am using firebase authentication, which only provide email and password, so storing more data of a user like role, name and other data I created a profile collection. and provide the profile id as user uid.In profile there is field called roles like (admin, customer, organiser). Now what I want is that only the creator of profile can read their data, and admin which is field in profile role can do anything.

```
 rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /profiles/{profile} {   
        allow create;
      allow read : if request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid == profile || resource.data.roles == 'admin');
    }
  }
}
```

the first condition is working fine which is `request.auth != null` and `request.auth.uid == profile` and this too.
and for getting all the user from profiles collection I have created a query.

```
const getDocument = async()=>{
    const q = query(collection(db, 'profiles'), where ('roles', '==', "customer"))
    const docSnap = await getDocs(q)
    docSnap?.forEach((doc)=>{
      return (
        setProfile(doc.data())
      )
    })
}
```

now the above query is giving me missing or insufficient error. If I change the roles to `where ('roles', '==', "admin")` then it give me user who are admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security [rules don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). Instead they merely check that your code only accesses data that it is permitted to by your rules. So it is really important that your code requests no more data than it is allowed to read by your rules.

Since your security rules require that:

```
(request.auth.uid == profile || resource.data.roles == 'admin')
```

You must pass one of these conditions in your code too. So your code must either only request `admin` users OR it must only read the user's own document. That first query would be:

```
query(collection(db, 'profiles'), where ('roles', '==', "admin")
```

Comment: Sir I don’t want that, what I want is the admin can get all profiles. What will be rules for that. In query if I pass roles == admin that it returns only user who are admin, and I want all users.

Comment: Sir let's say as an Admin I want all users what should be the security rules for the query of getting all users?

Comment: "I want is the admin can get all profiles" That's not what this part of your security rules does: `resource.data.roles == 'admin'`. This rule says that a user can only retrieve documents that have a `roles` field with the value `admin`.  I recommend spending some time in the documentation, specifically this section on role based access control: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#data-defined_attributes_and_roles

Comment: ``` 
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    function isAdmin() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles == 'admin';
    }
  
    match /profiles/{profile} {  
     allow create;
      allow read : if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == profile;
      allow list : if request.auth != null && isAdmin();
  
    }
  }
}
``` This is working now sir.